# No search hits after moving Elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to move an Elasticsearch index from a remote host to my local host. A bit of research had me find a tool called [elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) which seemed to be the right one for the job. As specified on its GitHub page, I ran the following command:

```
elasticdump --input=http://remote_host/index_name --ouput=http://localhost/index_name
```

After running it, the local index indeed contains the documents from the remote one. But when I pose a query to the local Elasticsearch's search API, I get no results while the same query returns several hits when posed to the remote Elasticsearch's API.

What is necessary to make the local search API work?

Comment: Does the GET http://remote_host/index_name/_mapping match the http://localhost/index_name/_mapping?  The docs say that it should copy that, but check it... Also does the mapping/settings refer to some external files such as a synonyms file or dictionary file?  Are there aliases involved that aren't being copied?  Are there scripts on disk that aren't being copied?  There just isn't enough information here to say what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now a mapping import/export flag you can use with elasticdump, which may be the issue:

- `elasticdump --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index --output=http://staging.es.com:9200/my_index --type=mapping`
- `elasticdump --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index --output=http://staging.es.com:9200/my_index --type=data`